# How to debug Serverless code locally with Visual Code or IntelliJ

Tags: serverless-framework

I went through almost a day to figure out how to debug Serverless code locally with Visual Code or IntelliJ but couldn't find good steps neither a proper answer to it

Please advise

Thanks